# Problems with webpack-dev-server React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am reading an article about Webpack the moment has come when I have to start Webpack but I get an error

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cra-tutorial@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cra-tutorial@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\suren\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-04T07_14_10_733Z-debug.log
```

Here are also screenshots:

[image: Screenshot-1]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "cra-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "link tutorial ",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode=development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production"
  },
  "author": "Suren Zakaryan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.11.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: are you using the `create-react-app`?

Comment: No, i no use `create-react-app`

Comment: so you need the valid package to handle your module

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot says there is an issue parsing your `HelloWorld` module since there is no appropriate loader. You need to install Babel to transpile ES2015 javascript, and Webpack to bundle your assets.

1. `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env`
2. `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react`
3. Add `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

4. Add `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const HWP = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
   entry: path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.js'),
   output: {
       filename: 'build.js',
       path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist')},
   module:{
       rules:[{
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel-loader'
       }]
   },
   plugins:[
       new HWP(
          {template: path.join(__dirname,'/src/index.html')}
       )
   ]
}
```